# Mocking Playwright library

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jasmine, playwright

Working on a project using the new playwright library.

I've started writing some unit tests and want to mock out portions of the library as I test.

Right now I'm getting the error `Cannot Read Property 'launch' of undefined.`

```
import MyModule from './myModule';
import { firefox } from 'playwright'

function bootStrapComponent() {
    return new MyModule();
};
describe('myModule Class', () => {
    var myModule;
    describe('main', () => {
        beforeEach(() => {
            myModule = bootStrapComponent();

        })

        it('should mock browswer', async() => {
            let browser = jasmine.createSpyObj('firefox', ['launch']);
            myModule.firefox.launch({});
            expect(browser.launch).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    });
```

I'm not sure I'm even doing this correctly.  Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Don't you need a firefox prop in MyModule?

Comment: I guess not, but I was just trying and that's where I landed.

Comment: Justin Young, sorry, did you mock the lib?

Comment: Could I ask - why do you want to mock the Playright browser? If you want to write a standard unit test without Playright, you can simply not import or call Playwright at all. But maybe I missed something?